# PostgreSQL Transaction Committing for hours

Tags: postgresql, linux, postgresql-8.4

I'm running into an issue whereby I have two connections from a user to my PostgreSQL server which have been running for about 4 hours and have been in a commit state for quite some time (at least 1 hour that I have been watching it). These connections are blocking other queries from running but themselves aren't blocked.

Here are the two connections in question.

```
postgres=# select * from pg_stat_activity where usename = 'xxxxx';
 datid | datname | procpid | usesysid | usename | current_query | waiting |          xact_start           |          query_start          |         backend_start         |  client_addr  | client_port
-------+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------+-------------
 20394 | xxxxxx  |   17509 |    94858 | xxxxx   | COMMIT        | f       | 2014-01-30 05:51:11.311363-05 | 2014-01-30 05:51:12.042515-05 | 2014-01-30 05:51:11.294444-05 | xx.xx.xxx.xxx |       63531
 20394 | xxxxxx  |    9593 |    94858 | xxxxx   | COMMIT        | f       | 2014-01-30 06:45:17.032651-05 | 2014-01-30 06:45:17.694533-05 | 2014-01-30 06:45:16.992576-05 | xx.xx.xxx.xxx |       63605
```

PID 9593 is the most problematic one which other users get blocked by this one. As far as the user is admitting to, he truncated his table, then did inserts in batches of 1,000 committing after each batches.

Currently this PID shows the following locks:

```
postgres=# select * from pg_locks where pid = 9593;
   locktype    | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction | pid  |        mode         | granted
---------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+------+---------------------+---------
 relation      |    20394 | 29173472 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 261/0              | 9593 | AccessExclusiveLock | t
 relation      |    20394 | 27794470 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 261/0              | 9593 | RowExclusiveLock    | t
 relation      |    20394 | 27794470 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 261/0              | 9593 | ShareLock           | t
 relation      |    20394 | 27794470 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 261/0              | 9593 | AccessExclusiveLock | t
 virtualxid    |          |          |      |       | 261/503292 |               |         |       |          | 261/0              | 9593 | ExclusiveLock       | t
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |     503213304 |         |       |          | 261/0              | 9593 | ExclusiveLock       | t
```

I can't kill this PID (nothing happens when I issue the kill command). I'm not sure what to do to diagnose this further and obviously resolve this.

Any input anyone?

Running PostgreSQL 8.4 on Ubuntu Linux server.

EDIT:

As I found other connections in a similar state where the commit was hanging, I looked further and found the following in the server logs:

```
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240540] postgres      D 0000000000000000     0 23220   8154 0x00000004
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240550]  ffff8800174c9d08 0000000000000082 ffff88041cd24728 0000000000015880
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240559]  ffff8806c678b110 0000000000015880 0000000000015880 0000000000015880
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240567]  0000000000015880 ffff8806c678b110 0000000000015880 0000000000015880
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240575] Call Trace:
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240582]  [<ffffffff810da010>] ? sync_page+0x0/0x50
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240590]  [<ffffffff81528488>] io_schedule+0x28/0x40
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240596]  [<ffffffff810da04d>] sync_page+0x3d/0x50
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240603]  [<ffffffff815289a7>] __wait_on_bit+0x57/0x80
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240610]  [<ffffffff810da1be>] wait_on_page_bit+0x6e/0x80
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240618]  [<ffffffff81078540>] ? wake_bit_function+0x0/0x40
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240627]  [<ffffffff810e4480>] ? pagevec_lookup_tag+0x20/0x30
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240634]  [<ffffffff810da665>] wait_on_page_writeback_range+0xf5/0x190
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240644]  [<ffffffff81053668>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x118/0x340
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240651]  [<ffffffff810da727>] filemap_fdatawait+0x27/0x30
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240659]  [<ffffffff811431b4>] vfs_fsync+0xa4/0xf0
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240667]  [<ffffffff81143239>] do_fsync+0x39/0x60
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240674]  [<ffffffff8114328b>] sys_fsync+0xb/0x10
Jan 30 02:29:45 server001 kernel: [3521062.240682]  [<ffffffff81012042>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

Comment: I have seen similar entries after high I/O load. Still not sure whether bad luck or really some connection.

Comment: I strongly suspect a disk or I/O subsystem fault on the server.

Comment: @CraigRinger - I think you're right. The strange thing is that at 2AM I got these alerts in the log file and since then, all day didn't get more messages in logs - however, the database connections are still hung as if PostgreSQL did not recover from those faults. Going to do an update of OS and such tonight (running 4 years old kernel).

Comment: @ETL check `dmesg` too - look for I/O errors, timeouts, HBA errors, etc. Take a fresh backup, and check your disks, raid subsystem, etc.

Comment: There needs to be another message right above that postgres D ... call trace printk, the one that would say e.g. CPU lock, process stuck for over 120 seconds, etc. That will more clearly indicate what the problem is, although the trace is already fairly clear - that looks like a fsync(2). Looks like the underlying device is broken or too slow?

Comment: Note also that you can try to send other signals to the process as described at e.g. http://serverfault.com/questions/35332/what-do-i-do-when-pg-cancel-backend-doesnt-work

Comment: Is database files running in a NAS or something in the network, like CIFS or NFS?

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini - no but thanks for checking. I have since changed server. I think there was some faults with the drives.

Comment: Did changing server make this problem go away?

Comment: @MichaelGreen - haven't experience this on the new server (running newer version of PG also). I think there might have been something wrong with a drive that somehow wasn't being reported by the hardware. But that's just a suspicion.

Comment: @ETL glad you moved to a new server. I suggest you to always use the latest stable version. Also, the `pg_stat_activity` table shipped with 9.* version is more complete. There are also two useful functions that probably should have helped you: `pg_cancel_backend(pid)` and `pg_terminate_backend(pid)` - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html

Comment: @ETL can you write what version you upgraded to and mark that answer as accepted so we know you're no longer entertaining answers? There is nothing more to be done here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since upgraded to version 9.4 and a whole new server so I can't debug this further. But I believe the problem was with a drive. I found a bad drive which wasn't reported as bad by the machine.